# Empty array on api get request Dart

Tags: api, dart

I could use some help. When making a GET request in Dart, I get an empty array. However, I can get a response in Postman. I'm rather stumped as to where the discrepancy is. I'm very new to Dart. I've tried more closely following the Postman code and didn't have any luck with that either.

My Dart code:

```
  void loadData() async {
    showLoading(context);
    try {
      hideDialog(context);
      // String url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';
      String url = '127.0.0.1:5000';
      String endpoint = '/carrier_loadboard';
      String option = 'Market';
      String orgId = '2';

      final queryParameters = {
        'option': option,
        'org_id': orgId,
      };

      final headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer$userToken',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': 'session=$sessionCookie',
      };

      var creds = json.encode({
        'email': 'carrier@domain.com',
        'password': 'thePassword',
      });

      final uri = Uri.http(url, endpoint, queryParameters);
      final response = await get(uri, headers: headers);

      // var request = Request(
      //     'GET',
      //     Uri.parse(
      //         'http://127.0.0.1:5000/carrier_loadboard?option=Market&org_id=2'));
      // request.body = creds;
      // request.headers.addAll(headers);

      // StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
        print('Load data success');
        List data = json.decode(response.body);
        print(data);
        if (data.isEmpty) {
          print('No data');
        }
      } else {
        print(response.reasonPhrase);
        print('Load data failed');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      devlog.log(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

And here is the code that Postman generates (which returns an array of data in Postman).

```
var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer tokenTokenToken',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'session=.cookieCodeCookieCode'
};
var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/carrier_loadboard?option='Market'&org_id='2''));
request.body = '''// {"email": "carrier@domain.com", "password":"thePassword"}\n''';
request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

This is the response in Dart:

```
[]
```

This is the first object in the Postman response:

```
[
    {
        "agent_id": null,
        "assigned_carrier_id": null,
        "carrier_org_id": 2,
        "commodity": null,
        "deliver_address": "700 4th St, San Francisco, CA 94107, USA",
        "deliver_appt": null,
        "deliver_appt_required": false,
        "deliver_date": "2021-10-22T17:46:00",
        "deliver_from_date": "2022-03-12T00:00:00",
        "deliver_to_date": null,
        "driver_id": null,
        "expected_delivery_bid": "1000",
        "expected_posting_bid": "1300",
        "id": 104,
        "load_num_broker": null,
        "load_num_carrier": null,
        "load_num_shipper": null,
        "margin": null,
        "notes": null,
        "office_hr_end": null,
        "office_hr_start": null,
        "org_created": null,
        "org_id_posted": 1,
        "org_id_reposted": 1,
        "org_name": null,
        "pickup_address": "801 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA 98104, USA",
        "pickup_appt": null,
        "pickup_appt_required": false,
        "pickup_date": "2021-10-18T17:46:00",
        "pickup_from_date": "2022-03-12T00:00:00",
        "pickup_to_date": null,
        "po_num": null,
        "poster_id": null,
        "shipper_id": null,
        "status": "Completed",
        "time_accepted": null,
        "time_posted": "2021-10-19T00:47:24.060521",
        "trailer_id": null,
        "trailer_type": "Double",
        "truck_id": "",
        "weight": "1000"
    },
]
```

Comment: are you sure    this is  an array `json.decode(response.body);`   ?

i think its `Map<String,dynamic>`.

Comment: for debugging `final data = json.decode(response.body)` . then you can see what actual value for `response.body`

Comment: please provide the snipped `response` from your `postman` when its response success

Comment: @pmatatias Thank you for the response. I added the information to my original post. Unfortunately final data = json.deconde(response.body) didn't work nor did Map<String,dynamic>.

Answer (score 0):

you `response.body` is an `Array` . but you convert it again here:

```
List data = json.decode(response.body);  // data is List<dynamic>
print(data); // it will return empty array
```

based on your postman response, response body is array, no need to `json.decode` if you assign the response to `List data`

what is [decode](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) do :

> dynamic decode(String source, {Object? Function(Object?, Object?)?
> reviver})
>
> Parses the string and returns the resulting Json object.

decode require String not List. thats why based on your postman response it should throw an error if you do like this `json.decode(response.body)`.

if you want to get the list without convert to Json Object all you have to do are remove json.decode

```
final data = response.body;
print (data); // if your api is success (200 ), this should not empty

// actually it same like 
print(response.body);
```

Comment: thank you again for the followup. Unfortunately, even when I do print(response.body) I get an empty array in the Debug Console.

Comment: if you print the array outside the method, you should `setState` 

also make sure your response status code == 200.

Comment: if you have to print `response.statusCode` what you got in debug console?

Comment: I get a 200 status code and empty array. It’s got me baffled

Comment: how its could posible, when  200 , but `print(response.body)` return empty list.

then something wrong from backend